# Applying a hibernate filter using Spring AOP

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, aop, aspectj

I am trying to apply a filter on a database table using Spring AOP. I want this filter to apply only for this table. I have configured an Aspect to apply the filter but I must have configured something incorrectly.

The joinpoint functionality never seems to be executed. I want it to retrieve a session from hibernates SessionFactory.getCurrentSession() and apply a filter to this.

My aspect class:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAspect {

@Pointcut("execution(* org.hibernate.SessionFactory.getCurrentSession(..))")
protected void hibernateSessionFetch() {

}


@AfterReturning(pointcut = "hibernateSessionFetch()", returning = "result")
public void enableFilter(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object result) {

    System.out.println("*********** ASPECT ************");

    Session session = (Session) result;

    User u = new User("John Smith", 20);

    // apply the filter
    Filter filter = session.enableFilter("restrictToUser");
    filter.setParameter("name", u.getName());

}
```

My target class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
@org.hibernate.annotations.DynamicInsert
@org.hibernate.annotations.Filter(
  name = "restrictToUser",
  condition="name = :name"
)
@Component
public class User extends com.system.admin.SkeletonDTO<User>
  implements java.io.Serializable {
// user information
}
```

And in XML I am configuring like this:

```
<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

Does anyone know what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: Without a component-scan your aspect will not get picked up. Also make sure it is in the same `ApplicationContext` as your `LocalSessionFactoryBean`.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum, unfortunately that did not work. I also tried to add te annotation `@Configurable` along with `<context:spring-configured />` but that didn't work either.

Comment: That won't change a thing. As stated make sure it is in the same context and that your `SessionFactory` is an actual bean (else it won't work).

Answer (score 0):

Change your class in the following way:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAspect {

@Pointcut("execution (* org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.SessionBuilderImpl.openSession(..))")
protected void hibernateSessionFetch() {

}


@AfterReturning(pointcut = "hibernateSessionFetch()", returning = "result")
public void enableFilter(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object result) {

    System.out.println("*********** ASPECT ************");

    if (result!= null && Session.class.isInstance(result)) {
        Session session = (Session) result;

        User u = new User("John Smith", 20);

        // apply the filter
        Filter filter = session.enableFilter("restrictToUser");
        filter.setParameter("name", u.getName());
    }
}
```

Then try to configue the AspectJ Load-Time Weaver in META-INF/aop.xml

```
<aspectj>

    <weaver options="-Xreweavable -verbose -showWeaveInfo">
        <include within="org.blablabla.MyAspect"/>
        <include within="org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.SessionBuilderImpl"/>
    </weaver>

    <aspects>
        <aspect name="org.blablabla.MyAspect"/>
    </aspects>

</aspectj>
```

**Alternative (and proven to be working) way without AspectJ is using TransactionManagerCustomizers:**

```
@Configuration
public class HibernateFilterConfig {
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            ObjectProvider<TransactionManagerCustomizers> transactionManagerCustomizers) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager() {
            @Override
            @NonNull
            protected EntityManager createEntityManagerForTransaction() {
                final EntityManager entityManager = super.createEntityManagerForTransaction();
                Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
                User u = new User("John Smith", 20);
                if (u != null && u.getName() != null) {
                    session.enableFilter("restrictToUser").setParameter("name", u.getName());
                }
                return entityManager;
            }
        };
        transactionManagerCustomizers.ifAvailable((customizers) -> customizers.customize(transactionManager));

        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

**Useful links:**
https://callistaenterprise.se/blogg/teknik/2020/10/17/multi-tenancy-with-spring-boot-part5/
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/25125